# Is there any solution to use "or" condition in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I have some problem in Laravel middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {
Route::view('/admin', 'admin');
```

Comment: Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::view('/admin', 'admin');

Comment: Please describe the problem you are having and how you have tried to solve it so far. Someone will be better able to help you that way.